# split a text file to what's before and after a given pattern

Tags: command-line, bash, split

I'd like to be able to split a text file to 2 files, such that the 1st output will include all the lines up-to (but not including) a given pattern, if the pattern is in the file, or the whole input file if the pattern is not there. And the second file should be all the lines after the pattern or empty file.

```
file1.txt:
a
b
c
```

$ split.sh file1.txt "b"

```
file1.txt.before:
a

file1.txt.after:
c
```

$ split.sh file1.txt "d"

```
file1.txt.before:
a
b
c

file1.txt.after:
```

I tried different sed commands, the closest I came up with is:

```
sed "1,/$2/!d" < $1 > $1.before
sed "1,/$2/d" < $1 > $1.after
```

but this has some problems:
- the before file is missing the 1st line of the input file
- the before file contains the pattern

Answer (score 2):

Use [csplit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) for things like this.

```
CSPLIT(1)                        User Commands                       CSPLIT(1)

NAME
       csplit - split a file into sections determined by context lines

-f, --prefix=PREFIX
          use PREFIX instead of 'xx'
--suppress-matched
          suppress the lines matching PATTERN
```

Regarding the regex part of the command:

```
Each PATTERN may be:

   INTEGER
          copy up to but not including specified line number

   /REGEXP/[OFFSET]
          copy up to but not including a matching line

   %REGEXP%[OFFSET]
          skip to, but not including a matching line

   {INTEGER}
          repeat the previous pattern specified number of times

   {*}    repeat the previous pattern as many times as possible

   A line OFFSET is a required '+' or '-' followed by a positive integer.
```

The command

```
csplit <file.txt> /<string>/ '{*}'
```

will split `<file.txt>` into parts based on how often it finds `<string>`. The `'{*}'` will repeat the search and creates multiple files for each occurrence. By default the files will be named `xx{number}`; use the `--prefix` option to change that. Adding `--suppress-matched` will omit the search string from the files.

Comment: almost, but the 2nd file includes the search pattern. --suppress-matched fixed it.

Comment: @steeldriver I can agree on that :=)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using Awk:

```
awk -v pattern='^b' '
  NR==1 {suff = ".before"} $0 ~ pattern {suff = ".after"; next} {print > FILENAME suff}
' file1.txt
```

Ex.

```
awk -v pattern='^b' 'NR==1 {suff = ".before"} $0 ~ pattern {suff = ".after"; next} {print > FILENAME suff}' file1.txt
```

giving

```
$ head file1.txt*
==> file1.txt <==
a
b
c

==> file1.txt.after <==
c

==> file1.txt.before <==
a
```